# ldconfig seems to be missing one of the symlinks

Tags: ld

I have a custom location (`/opt/lib`) added to my library paths by adding a file to `/etc/ld.so.conf`.  I compiled the git2 library and installed it there.

I am trying to install pygit which needs that library, but I keep getting an error that says that it can't find `-lgit2`.

I double checked and ldconfig seems to have missed that symlink.

Here is the output on the terminal.

```
/opt/lib$ ls
libgit2.so  libgit2.so.0.26.3  libgit2.so.26  pkgconfig
/opt/lib$ sudo ldconfig
/opt/lib$ sudo ldconfig -v | grep libgit
ldconfig: Can't stat /usr/local/lib/i386-linux-gnu: No such file or directory
ldconfig: Can't stat /usr/local/lib/i686-linux-gnu: No such file or directory
ldconfig: Can't stat /lib/i686-linux-gnu: No such file or directory
ldconfig: Can't stat /usr/lib/i686-linux-gnu: No such file or directory
ldconfig: Can't stat /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu: No such file or directory
ldconfig: Path `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu' given more than once
ldconfig: Path `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu' given more than once
ldconfig: /lib/i386-linux-gnu/ld-2.27.so is the dynamic linker, ignoring

ldconfig: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.27.so is the dynamic linker, ignoring

    libgit2.so.26 -> libgit2.so.0.26.3
ldconfig: /lib32/ld-2.27.so is the dynamic linker, ignoring
```

How do I get it to pick up `libgit2.so`?

Comment: "I am trying to install pygit". How? Add this info to the body of your question.

Answer (score 1):

`libgit2.so` is a link editor (ld) input file.  `/etc/ld.so.conf` configures paths for the run-time dynamic linker.  The relationship between these two is that the dynamic linker consumes output from the link editor.  Both happen to consult the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable, too.  Beyond that, they are complete separate programs, with different command line options.

So you need to set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` (which may be confusing later on, so it's not a good idea), or better, use `-L` to specify the path to the directory which contains the `libgit2.so` link editor input file.